# Find what Android version is been using?

Tags: android, fonts

I am developing an app which should perform differently based on the different Android Versions. For instance if a user has version below 3.0, the font should be "Anmol.ttf" but if it's above 3.0 the font should rather be "AnmolUniBani.ttf" How can I approach to this solution?

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways to go about this. I do

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

this gets the version number 10,11, 14,...

See the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) for the different possibilities.

I don't know if this is preferred but I set mine in a `static` variable on startup

```
public static int androidVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

then check against that. I'm going to move it to `SharedPreferences` but haven't yet.

**Code Example**

For 3.0 and above check that the `SDK_INT >= 11`. So in my example

```
if (Globals.androidVersion >= 11)
{
    // change fonts or whatever
}
```

It is in a `Globals` class for now where I put things for testing before making them more permanent as in `SharedPreferences` or the `DB`